# libvlc "VLC is unable to open the MRL 'C:\Users\Public\Videos\Sample Videos\Wildlife.mwv'"

Tags: python, vlc, pyside, libvlc

I am writing a PySide Python application that interfaces with VLC. Works just fine running on Ubuntu, but when I move to Windows, I can't even get VLC to open a video file.

I trimmed the VideoLAN PyQt example (http://git.videolan.org/?p=vlc/bindings/python.git;a=blob;f=examples/qtvlc.py;h=34aeedce116e05f575eb0ebffdacf8f06db80402;hb=HEAD) down to just a window and video player to try to figure out what's going wrong, and still get this error. Even when using the return from the open file dialog, I still get the same error.

Below is the very trimmed down version of the VideoLAN example:

```
import sys
import vlc
import user
from ctypes import pythonapi, c_void_p, py_object
from PySide import QtGui, QtCore

class Player(QtGui.QMainWindow):
  def __init__(self, master = None):
    QtGui.QMainWindow.__init__(self, master)

    self.setWindowTitle('Media Player')

    self.instance = vlc.Instance()
    self.mediaplayer = self.instance.media_player_new()

    self.createUI()

  def createUI(self):
    self.widget = QtGui.QWidget(self)
    self.setCentralWidget(self.widget)

    self.videoframe = QtGui.QFrame()
    self.palette = self.videoframe.palette()
    self.palette.setColor(QtGui.QPalette.Window,
                          QtGui.QColor(0, 0, 0))
    self.videoframe.setPalette(self.palette)
    self.videoframe.setAutoFillBackground(True)

    self.vboxlayout = QtGui.QVBoxLayout()
    self.vboxlayout.addWidget(self.videoframe)

    self.widget.setLayout(self.vboxlayout)

    self.OpenFile()

  def OpenFile(self, filename = None):
    if filename is None:
      filename = QtGui.QFileDialog.getOpenFileName(self, 'Open File', user.home)
      filename = filename[0]
    if not filename:
      return

    print filename
    self.media = self.instance.media_new(unicode(filename))
    self.mediaplayer.set_media(self.media)

    self.media.parse()
    self.setWindowTitle(self.media.get_meta(0))

    if sys.platform == 'linux2':
      self.mediaplayer.set_xwindow(self.videoframe.winId())
    elif sys.platform == 'win32':
      pythonapi.PyCObject_AsVoidPtr.restype = c_void_p
      pythonapi.PyCObject_AsVoidPtr.argtypes = [py_object]
      hWnd = pythonapi.PyCObject_AsVoidPtr(self.videoframe.winId())
      self.mediaplayer.set_hwnd(hWnd)
    elif sys.platform == 'darwin':
      self.mediaplayer.set_agl(self.videoframe.windId())

    self.mediaplayer.play()

if __name__ == '__main__':
  app = QtGui.QApplication(sys.argv)
  player = Player()
  player.show()
  player.resize(640, 480)

  sys.exit(app.exec_())
```

Answer (score 3):

if you are opening a file (and not a stream or some other source) libVLC requires you start the file path with "file:///" also when using file paths in python on windows it is required to use \ in order to escape the \ (a la \').

Thus the string used to call your file should look something like this:
'file:///C:\Users\Public\Videos\Sample Videos\Wildlife.mwv'

another note: if you can, it is best to take any spaces out of the file paths (i.e. "Sample Videos")